# Why no remote sensing or missiles?

Tags: warfare, alternate-reality

Why would a world with modern military technology experience a nearly complete lack of remote sensing and missile technology?  The world is exactly the same as ours but without any radar, sonar, infrared, or any other major remote sensing capabilities.  It also lacks any sort of space based technology as well as long range missiles.  What conditions would need to be different from our world to cause this to form?

Comment: I don't have the science to justify the effect, but if you could flood your world's atmosphere with enough natural radio noise then it might make the development of radio and therefore radio control much more difficult, even impossible.  Perhaps the planet's sun emits lots of energy across the entire electro-magnetic spectrum with enough variance that primitive filters could not adapt to it.  In such a world, line of sight would be the limit of everything.

Comment: If there were that much background noise, many telecommunications technologies would also become defunct. We would no longer be able to use wireless technologies. Everything would have to go through landlines.

Comment: Does it also lack eyeballs?

Comment: That's a world exactly like ours ... in **1930**. There are telephones, radio, rudimentary television, but no radar, laser, jet engines, etc. Radar will be invented as soon as a war becomes remotely possible -- radar works well-enough in ordinary radio ultrashort-wave band. The jet engine had already been invented, it just wasn't used with no war around to pour resources into research. Sonar was known but not used -- same reason, no war to justify the expense of making it practical.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Atleast not a believable modern world.

There's a lot of modern technology that is reliant on these technologies.

- Modern air traffic control would be lost without radar and commercial flight is pretty much out.
- Jet flight is out anyway as it's the basis of missiles...to believe we can create a jet engine for passenger use yet not attach a warhead to it is pretty far out there
- Radio is out.  Very hard to believe we could somehow transmit radio waves yet somehow complete ignore other uses of detecting radio waves (radar)
- could we possibly get cell phones to work if the cell phones couldn't detect the incoming signal?  With the exception of land lines, no communication network could exist.
- The internet is likely nonexistent and communications would be badly hindered without spaceflight and satellites.
- Could lasers come to be without infra-red usage (CDs and Blueray...mouse...or any automatic door/light)?
- Oil is likely left mostly undiscovered...hard to justify coming up with the need for seismic detection yet being completely unable to dream of sonar
- No GPS or other position signals

Ya, there is a pretty big disconnect here...no 'remote sensing' basically negates wireless communication and everything thats come along with this, which is a huge part of our modern society. To be this cherry picking of lacking technology, you'd have to have an extremely one tracked mind population lacking creativity.